# java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-01795: maximum number of expressions in a list is 1000.how can pass the row in 1000's slot

Tags: java, oracle-adf

someone suggest out OR condition in IN condition but params come dynamicaly how we divide it in 1000's slot for OR condition

## Stack trace:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-01795: maximum number of expressions in a list is 1000
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:457)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:405)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:889)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:476)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:204)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:540)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:217)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:924)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:1261)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1419)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3752)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3806)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1667)
    at oracle.jbo.server.ViewObjectImpl.getQueryHitCount(ViewObjectImpl.java:4840)
    at oracle.jbo.server.ViewObjectImpl.getQueryHitCount(ViewObjectImpl.java:4751)
    at oracle.jbo.server.QueryCollection.getEstimatedRowCount(QueryCollection.java:4011)
    at oracle.jbo.server.ViewRowSetImpl.getEstimatedRowCount(ViewRowSetImpl.java:2633)
    at oracle.jbo.server.ViewObjectImpl.getEstimatedRowCount(ViewObjectImpl.java:10426)
    at oracle.adf.model.bc4j.DCJboDataControl.estimateRowCount(DCJboDataControl.java:1553)
    at oracle.adf.model.bc4j.DCJboDataControl.getEstimatedRowCount(DCJboDataControl.java:1505)
    at oracle.adf.model.binding.DCIteratorBinding.getEstimatedRowCount(DCIteratorBinding.java:3825)
    at oracle.jbo.uicli.binding.JUCtrlRangeBinding.getEstimatedRowCount(JUCtrlRangeBinding.java:117)
    at oracle.jbo.uicli.jui.JUTableBinding$JUTableModel.getRowCount(JUTableBinding.java:1401)
    at javax.swing.JTable.getRowCount(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JTable.valueChanged(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.fireValueChanged(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.fireValueChanged(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.fireValueChanged(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.changeSelection(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.changeSelection(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.removeSelectionIntervalImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.clearSelection(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JTable.clearSelection(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JTable.clearSelectionAndLeadAnchor(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JTable.tableChanged(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel.fireTableChanged(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel.fireTableDataChanged(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.jbo.uicli.jui.JUTableBinding$JUTableModel.fireTableDataChangedRestoreSelection(JUTableBinding.java:1040)
    at oracle.jbo.uicli.jui.JUTableBinding$JUTableModel._refreshLater(JUTableBinding.java:1283)
    at oracle.jbo.uicli.jui.JUTableBinding$JUTableModel.access$1000(JUTableBinding.java:967)
    at oracle.jbo.uicli.jui.JUTableBinding$JUTableModel$1.run(JUTableBinding.java:1229)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at maxxton.newyse.client.cursor.WaitCursorEventQueue.dispatchEvent(WaitCursorEventQueue.java:50)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Dialog$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Dialog$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.awt.Dialog.show(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(Unknown Source)
    at maxxton.newyse.client.error.JErrorHandlerDialog.show(JErrorHandlerDialog.java:435)
    at maxxton.newyse.client.error.JErrorHandlerDialog.reportException(JErrorHandlerDialog.java:230)
    at maxxton.newyse.client.error.ErrorHandler.showDialog(ErrorHandler.java:43)
    at maxxton.newyse.client.error.ErrorHandler.showDialog(ErrorHandler.java:31)
    at maxxton.newyse.client.cursor.WaitCursorEventQueue.dispatchEvent(WaitCursorEventQueue.java:54)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: so you're doing `select * from table where col1 in (.....)` and the contents of the IN clause is an unbounded list?

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish your goal by using OR conditions in the WHERE clause to break up your IN statements into groups of 1,000 items.  Here's an example:

```
SELECT 
    customer_name 
FROM
    customer 
WHERE 
    customer_id in (1,2,4,...,1000) OR
    customer_id in (1001,1002,...,2000) OR
    customer_id in (2001,2002,...,3000)
```